# In C++, is there a simple way to get command calls with parameters via iostream::cin?

Tags: c++, function, io, cin

I'm writing a program that is supposed to be used by another program to execute certain commands, some of which have parameters.  I've seen that cin and cout appear to be the best way to communicate between the two programs, but I'm not sure I see a simple way of accepting the commands.
E.g.
 one expected input would be "quit()", which does not have parameters, but "new_array(32)" would have one. Three functions need parameters, two of which expect a string and the other an int.

I thought about trying to parse the strings, but wasn't sure if this was the best way to go about it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I am trying to stay in standard C++11 features for portability concerns.

Comment: To clarify: the program you are writing is meant to be running continuously? Or is it simply meant to receive a command, execute some code, then return some value to the other program?

Comment: How does the first program use the second program? Does it use a pipe, or does it fork a sub process for example?

Comment: It is supposed to run for up to several hours, I intended at first to put the commands in a queue, but I'm not sure how that will work out either since it just temporarily sidesteps the issue until farther down the line.

Comment: I am unsure specifically, about the first program, it was not written by myself, it is a server management program for a Go server. They specified exactly which commands need to be supported.

Comment: So how does that server management program communicate its commands to the program you are writing?

Comment: The other program is a platform specific (*nix or Win , 32/64 variants) and comes as an executable,  best as I can tell it uses the standard console i/o

Comment: commands are passed in with an optional id number, the command name, and any parameters required in to format [id] command_name [args], space delimited

Answer (score 0):

You can write a complete domain-specific language using boost::spirit. Your first attempt will consume at least a week of your life, but after a few days you'll find it fun, flexible and powerful.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I may look into that for my own later purposes even though it is not in the standard library, at least I will have a free week after I finish this project

Comment: if you're determined to use only the standard library, have a look at std::regex. That'll help crack the commands.